# need to replace the exact match only using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

content "#menuHover; #menuHoverColor;"

I need to replace the first `#menuHover` with `#fff`.

When I use `str_replace` it replace all the "menuHover" string in the content, but I need to replace the first one only.

Comment: Hmm.. have you tried str_replace like this? $newData = str_replace("menuHover;", "ffff;", $data);

Comment: yes, its replacing the second one also

Comment: Just add the semicolon :)

Comment: its sample code there will be possibilities of without semicolon also

Comment: But this is css right?

Comment: yes its css code... css file generating dynamically

Comment: Fine then ^_^ since css code is not particular with semi-colon. You should use the preg_replace instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Use 4th parameter (limit = 1)

For example:

```
$string = '#menuHover #menuHoverHover';

$replacedString = preg_replace('/menuHover/', 'fff', $string, 1);

print_r ($replacedString);
```

If You want to replace exactly "menuHover" string regardless of its location You may use next code:

```
$replacedString = preg_replace('/#menuHover(?!\S)/', '#fff', $string, 1);
```

Another improvement consider semicolon:

```
$replacedString = preg_replace('/#menuHover([;]?)(?!\S)/', '#fff$1', $string, 1);
```

Comment: can you share the preg_replace code with reg_exp for my prob

Comment: [php sandbox code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/534be43c548278701abc6763ecd01ebd99919aeb)

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries:

```
$str = "#menuHover; #menuHoverColor;";
$str = preg_replace("/\bmenuHover\b/", "fff", $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the str_replace will suffice, just add the semi-colon:

```
$string = "#menuHover; #menuHoverColor;";
$newString = str_replace("menuHover;", "fff;", $string);
echo $newString;
```

or using preg_replace

```
$string = "#menuHover; #menuHoverColor;";
$newString = preg_replace("/menuHover/", "fff", $string, 1);
echo $newString;
```